# Blender 2.82 Liquid Simulation: Flask mesh as an obstacle just passes through

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have a flask mesh (UV Sphere+Cylinder Bridged -> Solidify Modifier -> Subdiv Modifier), applied as an obstacle in Bender 2.8 Mantaflow sim.

The liquid just passes through. I double checked the normals of the Flask and tried various settings but cant seem to get the liquid to contain inside the flask.

Please Help.

[image]

[image: Step 1: Add Quick Liquid.]
[image: Step 2: Flask as the Obstacle.]

[image: Baked Result]

[image: Baked Result]

[image: Outside Normals]

[image: Inside Normal + Hull]

[image]

Comment: Found a tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSlH1izJmxE

Hope this helps you!

Comment: What you are looking for and is in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2O0QcLpAxV4&t=370s